# Fixing weird indentation in text file with php

Tags: php, parsing, text

I'm taking [this file](http://www.anc.org/MASC/texts/Homosexuality.txt) and splitting it up into sentences. The issue is that its formatted weirdly. I need to remove all the random new lines, indentations and unneeded spaces. Is there a way to do this with php?

I am currently using

```
$test= file_get_contents("text.txt");
$stringtest = str_replace(PHP_EOL,'', $test);
```

But I am getting weird behavior when I try to split up the sentences. Is there a way to do this?

The weird behavior is that when I print out the text

```
echo $stringtest;
```

There are unseen characters between lines where a newline/weird_spacing used to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to merge all whitespaces to a single space. Also you probably want to remove whitespace at the beginning and end. Try this:

```
$test = trim($test);
$test = preg_replace('/\s+/s', ' ', $test);
```